# uiOutput not displaying with shiny server

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-server

I have a shiny app that is working fine locally, whether I open it in a window or the browser, but after putting it onto our shiny server I am getting some unexpected behavior.

I have two plots that get displayed using uiOutput. The first displays after loading a data file, and the second is just a zoomed plot which appears when the user selects a region from the first plot and double clicks. After putting this app on our server and using it in a browser, the first plot appears when the user uploads a file, but the second plot will not display (it is completely blank - no data points, axes or labels).

What is strange is that the data in this second plot can still be interacted with. I have included hover functionality so that when the user hovers over a point in the second plot, information gets displayed about the point in a small text window. Even though the second plot never appears, if I move the mouse over the region where the plot should be, this hover information gets displayed correctly. Depending on the size of the region selecting for zooming (i.e. if it is large), the zoomed image may not fit in the window making scrollbars necessary. If I select a large region for zooming, scrollbars appear as if the image is there, but the plot is as I said blank. I can render the zoomed plot as a pdf and that looks correct, but this isn't what I want.

As I said, everything works fine locally and this only happens after putting the app on our server. The same thing happens in Firefox, Safari and Chrome. This has to be something related to the shiny server but I have no idea what as both plots are being rendered in the same way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've managed to figure this out. In server.R when I generate the zoomed plot, I am doing two things. First, I am creating a pdf as follows:

```
pdf("z_plot.pdf")
plot()
...
dev.off()
```

The purpose of this is to have a plot that can be downloaded if required. After this, I am issuing the commands to render the plot in my shiny app. This is all being done in the same reactive expression, which for some reason works locally but when run on a shiny server only the pdf gets generated. I just had to separate the plotting commands into two reactive expressions and everything worked fine.